# Conditional and UIButton

Tags: ios, swift

I have two buttons in the first view controller each representing a game a user can play (one bingo game and one memory game).  I passed these two buttons from the first view controller to the third view controller through a segue and created two UIButton variables in the receiving view controller(thirdVC).

Now, I need to create a conditional statement in the third view controller for when the user presses the bingo button in the first view controller, the user segues to the bingo game in order to play the game or if the user presses the memory game button in the first view controller, the user segues to the memory game in order to play the memory game.  In other words, if user presses bingo game button, perform BingoSegue to the bingo game or if the user presses memory game button, perform memorySegue to the memory game.  I am confused with how to code the actual buttons since the IBAction button code is in the first view controller.  I have been working on this for weeks and have researched this in stackoverflow, but have not been successful.  I am assuming I need a bool.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
var bingoButton = UIButton()
var memoryButton = UIButton()

var isSelected = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

//bingoButton:   

if isSelected {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "bingoSegue", sender: sender)
    print("bingoSegue")

}

//memoryButton:

if isSelected {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "memorySegue", sender: sender)
    print("memorySegue")

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the storyboard you can add two different segues by control dragging from the buttons to the specific destination viewcontroller. Then you do not have to perform checks and segues manually in code:

[image: example]

If you have to pass data from the first viewcontroller to the "game viewcontrollers" you can name those segues and check for them in the first viewcontroller's `prepareForSegue` function:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "Bingo" {
        // ...
    } else if segue.identifier == "Memory" {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I could add a new VC and 2 buttons, but I'd rather have less view controllers in the app.  I would prefer to have the buttons in the first view controller.

Comment: I am not too sure if I understand what you are trying to do to be honest... :) You are talking about a first and a third viewcontroller. What about the second? So you only have two viewcontrollers in total?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, reset.
You messed up a little. You can achieve your goal in different ways, the easiest way, if you don't need to pass data from the first ViewController to the others VC, is this:

I imagine that the storyboard is composed by 3 view controller.
The first VC have the 2 buttons.
You can easily achieve your goal doing this:

- erase the code that you wrote in the view controller (it's wrong)
- in the storyboard, right click without release on the bingoButton, drag the cursor over the bingo view controller, release the mouse button. In the context menu select the first option: "Show"
- do the same with the memoryButton over the memory view controller.

If you need to pass data from the first VC to the games VC, you have various options, that are a little more complex to explain

Comment: Yes, the storyboard has three view controllers before the game view controllers.  I do need to pass data from the first VC to the games view controllers, so I cannot drag each button to each game in the storyboard.  I am currently working on an enum and switch statements.

Answer (score 0):

I received help with the solution.  Here it is:

Create a new swift file:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

enum Game {
    case bingo
    case memory
}
```

In the first view controller, you are assigning each button to each game and moving them to the second view controller:

```
 var gameToPlay: Game? = nil

    @IBAction func playBingoButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    gameToPlay = Game.bingo
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "GameSegue", sender: self)
    print("BingoGame")

     }

   @IBAction func playMemoryButton(_ sender: Any) {

    gameToPlay = Game.memory
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "GameSegue", sender: self)
    print("MemoryGame")

}

   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
     if let secondViewController = segue.destination as? SecondViewController {
        secondViewController.gameToPlay = self.gameToPlay
    }
   }
```

In the second view controller, you are passing the buttons to the third view controller:

```
  var gameToPlay: Game? = nil

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
     if let thirdViewController = segue.destination as? thirdViewController {
     thirdViewController.gameToPlay = self.gameToPlay

    }
}
```

In the third view controller, the user picks the vocabulary words they would like to play in my app.  This is why I have a button called "vocabularyButtons" and placed the code here.  When the user picks the vocabulary words they would like to play, the user will segue to the game they chose in the first view controller.

```
var gameToPlay: Game? = nil 

 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

@IBAction func vocabularyButtons(_ sender: Any) {
    if let gameToPlay = gameToPlay {
        switch (gameToPlay){
        case .bingo:
             performSegue(withIdentifier: "BingoSegue", sender: sender)
        case .memory:
             performSegue(withIdentifier: "MemorySegue", sender: sender)
        }   
       }
      }
     }
```

Answer (score -1):

As per my knowledge tag may help you. Just change the viewDidLoad() as follows.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    bingoButton.tag = 0 //Just a notation or indicator
    memoryButton.tag = 1

}
```

And

```
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    //bingoButton:   

    if sender.tag == 0 {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "bingoSegue", sender: sender)
        print("bingoSegue")

    }
    else if sender.tag == 1 {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "memorySegue", sender: sender)
        print("memorySegue")

    }
   }
```

Just try and get back to us. Hope it will help you.

Comment: No, in this way you achieve only to get a loop. performSegue will call prepareForSegue that will call performSegue and so on.

Comment: Present Option may be better than segue in case of data passing to new vc or simply showing it.

Comment: Nah, I think that the best option to pass is through a segue with identifier, and in the prepareForSegue (checking the identifier) cast the destination view controller to a var, and set directly the public var of the destination